# How to exclude one folder in grunt-durandal

Tags: gruntjs, durandal

For example

```
durandal: {
main: {
    src: ['app/**/*.*', 'lib/durandal/**/*.js'],
    options: {
        name: '../lib/require/almond-custom',
        baseUrl: requireConfig.baseUrl,
        mainPath: 'app/main',
        paths: mixIn({}, requireConfig.paths, { 
            'almond': '../lib/require/almond-custom.js' 
        }),
        exclude: [],
        optimize: 'none',
        out: 'build/app/main.js'
    }
}}
```

My task is to exclude files in 'app/test/' folder. I tried to add 'app/test/**/**.*', but exception occurs says 'no such files or directory'.

So what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [globbing patterns](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) section of the grunt docs state:

> `!` at the beginning of a pattern will negate the match

Change the value of the `src` property in your `durandal` task to the following:

```
src: ['app/**/*.*', '!app/test/**', 'lib/durandal/**/*.js'],
```

**Note** the addition of `'!app/test/**'` in the array of globbing patterns.